# Autocomplete in eclipse skipping getters and setters

Tags: java, eclipse, autocomplete

I am looking for a while now for functionality in eclipse which will allow me to skip get and set part of autocomplete item , for example Class Person have field name and getter and setter for this field . Now when i start typing

```
Person p = new Person();
p.getN-> autocomplete gives me one item getName 

//what i would like to get is 

p.n-> autocomplete gives me two sugesstions getName and setName
```

I know those are only three letters to type , but when i type them so many times it really makes a difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there's no functionality like that in Eclipse, as far as I know.

*However*, Eclipse *does* support CamelCase searches in most places, so typing `p.gN` followed by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Space</kbd> should suggest `getName()` (probably as the first result).

Answer (score 3):

One step in your direction: eclipse supports CCN (CamelCaseNotation ;) ), so simply type

```
p.gN
```

and it should offer the `getName()` method.

Answer (score 2):

You can check [Eclipse Code Recommenders](http://eclipse.org/recommenders/) . I don't know if if features exactly what you're looking for, but it does nice stuff with autocompletion.

Answer (score 1):

There is a subwords completion engine for Eclipse. See http://code-recommenders.blogspot.com/2011/08/eclipse-subwords-completion-1-here-you.html for more details on this.

Best,
Marcel

Answer (score 0):

You can create the getter and setter manually as well for example:

```
public class Funcionario {
private String nome;
private String cpf;
private double salario;
}
```

Then inside the class you can typo getN and then type Ctrl. + Space. This way Eclipse will suggest you a getter method for nome, the same goes for setN and then type Ctrl. + Space.